# mysql character set conversion

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I have the following UTF-8 table:

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `description` mediumtext,
  `description_info` mediumtext,
  `rights` mediumtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

inside a UTF-8 database:

```
CREATE DATABASE `DB` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */
```

in this table there are rows with LATIN1 characters, like: Ã¨ or Ã²

My question is: how can I convert those characters?

THX!

Answer (score 0):

Use a [CONVERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-convert.html):

```
SELECT 
    description,
    CONVERT(description USING utg8)
FROM
    `table`
```

Comment: Thx @Benni, but i would like to convert the content of the DB, not the output of SELECT statements;

Comment: Do a `ALTER TABLE mytable CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8`

Comment: thx again, this was my first attempt but does not work... I have already posted a solution that works...

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution here: http://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/16/utf8-data-on-latin1-tables-converting-to-utf8-without-downtime-or-double-encoding/

Those are the steps I have applied to convert latin1 text inside the 'description' column to UTF8:

```
ALTER TABLE table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET latin1 -- this is because my table is in UTF8
ALTER TABLE table CHANGE description description BLOB;
ALTER TABLE table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8, CHANGE description description mediumtext;
```

I don't know if this is the most effective method to this... but it works!